# Python - How can I separate characters and integers from a string into sub-strings?

Tags: python, string, integer, character, substring

I am writing a program that allows the user to create expedition kit lists. The last area I need to configure is multiplying the amounts of equipment (from a saved expedition) per person by how many people are on the expedition, to give the user how much of that piece of equipment they will need.

However, the problem is, when the user enters how much of a certain equipment they would like, the unit goes with the amount.
For example, in the file, it looks like this:
Water
100ml

So, I need to multiply the "100" by a number, but need to separate it from "ml" first.
I have no code necessary to show, as I don't have any idea where to start.

Note: I am using python 3.2, I can easily change some syntax, but any extra effort to change it would be great, but don't bother too much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the values using `re.match`:

```
>>> import re
>>> item = "Water\n100ml\n"
>>> re.match(r"([0-9]+)([a-z]+)", item.split()[1], re.I).groups()
('100', 'ml')
```

And then do whatever you need to do with them.

---

**EDIT:**
For your second point in your comment, if you have a file in specified format you could do:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    items = list(zip(data[0::2], data[1::2]))  # A list of items like ('Water', '100ml')
```

And then you could use the previous regex for each item in that `list`, except with `some_item[1]` as the string to be searched; where `some_item` is the current value during for example an iteration.

Comment: Found a problem when using this, the line in the .txt file isn't "Water 100ml", this website blocked me from entering a paragraph, so the text in the file is: "Water\n100ml\n". And nother factor,(this is the bit i could do, but for means of shorter, more efficient code, i thought someone with better experience would have a better way) is that there will be multiple items in the file, like this: "Water\n100ml\nRope\n1m...etc"

Comment: @wizton `"Water\n100ml\n".split()` still gets the two items just fine.

Comment: Yeah, as I pressed add comment i realised that should be fine, and then saw a mistake in my code, but the second problem is bugging me

Comment: @wizton See edits. That is how you could group every two lines.

Comment: Now that i get round to putting that into my full code, I've come up with the error: "zips are not subscript-able", this is when i go through the list to use that regex on each

Comment: @wizton Ah, yes I forgot- Python 3. You need to convert the zip object to a list. See my edit.

Comment: '    for i in range(len(amountsUpdate[:])):
        amountsUpdate[i]=str(re.match(r"([0-9]+)([a-z]+)",str(amountsUpdate[i]).split()[1],re.I)).groups()' this is me trying to do it, but 'str' has no .split

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Water 100ml"
>>> re.sub(r'\d+', lambda m: str(int(m.group())*5), s)
'Water 500ml'
```

Comment: Be aware - this matches every since number "group." If there happens to be a numeric character as part of the item name, it will also be multiplied. @Alex Thornton's solution makes sure the regex item returned at least starts with a number which prevents some of that issue, but it still fails when the item name itself starts with any numbers.